# Declare static deque of pointers in a class

Tags: c++, visual-c++, static

I have a class named Foo with static deque of pointers:

**Foo.h:**

```
class Foo : public Base
{
public:
    static std::deque <Aircraft*> aircrafts;
    void updateAircrafts();
...
}
```

**Foo.cpp:**

```
#include "Foo.h"
void Foo::updateAircrafts()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Foo::aircrafts.size(); i++) {
    ...
    }
}
```

When I'm compiling, I get the following error:

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static class std::deque > Foo::aircrafts" (?aircrafts@Foo@@0V?$deque@PEAVAircraft@@V?$allocator@PEAVAircraft@@@std@@@std@@A)   QtGuiApplication1   C:\Users\a_kadirov\source\repos\QtGuiApplication1\Foo.obj   1

and

> Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  QtGuiApplication1   C:\Users\a_kadirov\source\repos\QtGuiApplication1\x64\Debug\QtGuiApplication1.exe   1
>   Where could be the problem?

I also need to access deque from outside the class, so it must be accessible to other classes. So moving static deque declaration to .cpp file may not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building C++17 or above then you could use the [inline specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline) :

`static inline std::deque <Aircraft*> aircrafts;`

Otherwise, you can define `aircrafts` in `Foo.cpp` :

```
std::deque <Aircraft*> Foo::aircrafts;
void Foo::updateAircrafts()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Foo::aircrafts.size(); i++) {

    }
}
```

Note that the above still requires a declaration in the header. And `aircrafts` should only be defined once, other files will be able to link it.

Comment: Thanks! defining deque in cpp file worked! Before, I didn't know how to declare deque in header and define it in cpp, now it's clear!